# surficial and superficial

Tags: word-usage, variants

I know that I can use surficial related to describe concepts related to the surface of the earth (or a planet)... so surficial aquifers, surficial geology, surficial deposits and so on. All the time I have looked an a dictionary, these are the only exaples that I have found.

In some documents (written by non anglophone, probably) I have found however "surficial" used to describe something related to the surface of a material. For example "surficial coating" of a nanoparticle.

I would use "superficial" in this case, but it is possible that I haven't found more technical examples because they are very specific.

So how does it sound to a native speaker? Would you use "surficial" for a surface of a molecule, a nanomaterial, and so on? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure about the very specific case you mention, but neither 'surficial' nor 'superficial' is the idiomatic choice for features on more everyday surfaces. The attributive usage is idiomatic. Collocations given by [OZDIC](https://www.ozdic.com/collocation-dictionary/surface) are: SURFACE + NOUN
area | level | layer
_the surface layer of the skin_
| temperature, tension | water
_Surface water made driving conditions hazardous._

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: What @Edwin said. Google Books claims 92 written instances of [a surficial coating](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+surficial+coating%22), and all the examples I've looked at seem to be relating to the "surface of the earth" sense. But there are an estimated 37,300 instances of [a **surface** coating](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+surface+coating%22) - the vast majority of which aren't really connected to that specialised sense.

Answer (score 3):

Surficial is a technical word with which most people are (I think) not familiar.  Superficial is a much more commonly used word which has a meaning similar to "shallow", both in the sense of describing someone's personality and also describing a thin, and usually easily damaged, layer of something on top of something else.

Domain-specific language, eg in molecular science or whatever the domain you refer to is called, generally has its own rules and conventions which are outside the scope of this site.  So, I can't answer whether it's the right word to use in a specific scientific context like nanomaterials.

Comment: I have purloined 'Domain-specific language, eg  ... , generally has its own rules and conventions which are outside the scope of this site.' for the list of 'not-on-topic' reasons I keep.

Comment: Sorry in my experience I usually answer questions about technical German or Italian all the time even in field far away from mine. I had no idea this was considered so "technical"... because surfaces are everywhere and basic science is part of public education. To me this was not a "specific domain" question, but more of a "I finished high school" question, in many countries it would be strange you did not read something like that in a chemistry or biology book before you were 18. Maybe that's a clue it is just used in geology.

Comment: @Alexmar983 congratulations, your high school science education seems to be much more advanced than mine!  Regardless of that, "surficial" is not a commonly used word in English.